# SURF matched points in simulink

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, simulink, matlab-cvst

i tried to create a simulink a block that makes a template matching using surf points following this example:
http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html
The block receives input scene video signal (as the 'clutteredDesk') and a constant template image (as 'stapleRemover' box image). I used Matlab Function block (Embedded MATLAB Function Block) to do that and inside it i wrote:

```
function out = fcn(in, template)


coder.extrinsic('detectSURFFeatures');
coder.extrinsic('indx2mtempl');
coder.extrinsic('extractFeatures');
coder.extrinsic('matchFeatures');
coder.extrinsic('estimateGeometricTransform');
coder.extrinsic('transformPointsForward'); 



scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(in); %punti caratteristici dello scenario
templPoints = detectSURFFeatures(template);



[boxFeatures, templPoints] = extractFeatures(template, templPoints);
[sceneFeatures, scenePoints] = extractFeatures(in, scenePoints);





boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures);

s = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,2));
s = size(boxPairs);


[matchTempl,matchScene] = indx2mtempl(templPoints,scenePoints, boxPairs);
if s(1) < 3

    out = single(zeros(1,8));
else


tform = estimateGeometricTransform(matchTempl, matchScene, 'affine');


boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
        size(template, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
        size(template, 2), size(template, 1);... % bottom-right
        1, size(template, 1);...                 % bottom-left
        1, 1];                   % top-left again to close the polygon

newBoxPolygon = coder.nullcopy(single(zeros(5,2)));
newBoxPolygon = transformPointsForward(tform, boxPolygon);

out = coder.nullcopy(single(zeros(1,8)));



out = ([newBoxPolygon(1,1) newBoxPolygon(1,2)...
    newBoxPolygon(2,1) newBoxPolygon(2,2) ...
    newBoxPolygon(3,1) newBoxPolygon(3,2) ...
    newBoxPolygon(4,1) newBoxPolygon(4,2)]);


end
```

where indx2mtempl is a function that extract matched points location for Geometric Transformation estimation:

```
function [matchlocTempl,matchlocScene]  = indx2mtempl(SUpoints1,SUpoints2,pairs)


loc1 = SUpoints1.Location;
loc2 = SUpoints2.Location;
matchlocTempl = loc1(pairs(:,1),:);
matchlocScene = loc2(pairs(:,2),:);
```

I would check the number of matched point checking the number of rows by size(boxPairs). As you can read if mathced points are less then 3 it does not estimate the geometric transformation. I tried it with video 'cat_video.bin' (using 'read from a binary file' block) and cat_target.png as template image but it does not detect the cat_target. I think it checks number of matched points only one time.